# jstree is not populated in IE 11.0.29

Tags: javascript, jquery

i used jstree plugins for json data response, it's not populated in IE 11.0.29, please help.
[image]

Comment: its's working in IE 11.0.27, but not  IE 11.0.29

Comment: it's working fine on IE 11.0.29 also... (this issues occurred due to my system IE currepted, apologies for the same.  )